# StructureMap: How to supply System.Web.HttpRequestBase to a method?

Tags: c#, structuremap, ioc-container

I'm trying to implement a wrapper for Cookies, as outlined here:

http://chwe.at/blog/post/2009/01/28/Testable-and-reusable-cookie-access-with-ASPNet-MVC-RC.aspx

But StructureMap is failing with the error:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.Web.HttpRequestBase,
System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,     
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

I think this is because I'm trying to get StructureMap to supply parameters for the following method:

```
    public CookieContainer(HttpRequestBase request, HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        Check.IsNotNull(request, "request");
        Check.IsNotNull(response, "response");

        _request = request;
        _response = response;
    }
```

I've tried adding the following to the StructureMap registry:

```
        ForRequestedType<HttpRequestBase>()
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<HttpRequestBase>();

        ForRequestedType<HttpResponseBase>()
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<HttpResponseBase>();
```

but this fails with the error:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  180
StructureMap cannot construct objects of Class System.Web.HttpRequestBase, 
System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 because there is no public constructor found.
```

How can I get StructureMap to supply the `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpResponseBase` objects to the method?

Comment: I've never used StructureMap specifically, but you can't create an instance of HttpRequestBase (it's an abstract class). Try passing HttpContext.Request to StructureMap instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is because HttpRequestBase is abstract and SM can do nothing about it.

Use the factory Methode

```
ForRequestedType<HttpRequestBase>().TheDefault.Is
  .ConstructedBy(() => HttpContext.Request);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I don't need the overloaded constructor.. so all i had to do was delete this:

```
public CookieContainer(HttpRequestBase request, HttpResponseBase response)
{
    Check.IsNotNull(request, "request");
    Check.IsNotNull(response, "response");

    _request = request;
    _response = response;
}
```

This constructor is only used to create a mock cookie container, into which you pass mock `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpResponseBase` objects.

Comment: Hey, i am reading the same article and trying to figure out the same issue. You mentioned that the constructor is only used in mock so what will the real implementation used in this case? We need to assign some value to HttpRequestBase and HttpResponseBase to make that work. Please let me know.